# Elementary proof $\sum_{n> N}\frac{1}{n^2} < 1/N $

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

Is there an elementary proof (not using integrals) $$\sum_{n> N}\frac{1}{n^2} < 1/N $$ for this sum?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\sum_{n> N}\frac{1}{n^2}<\sum_{n> N}\frac{1}{n(n-1)}=\cdots?$$

This proves that  $$\sum_{n> N}\frac{1}{n^2}<\frac 1 N$$

actually, which might be the intended inequality.